# unable to change the value using setState

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using React.js but I cannot achieve to change the value of my variable `test`.

Here is the code of App.js :

```
function App() {
  const [test, setTest] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <myNavBar handleTest={(test) => setTest(test)} />
      <div>
          {test ? <Test/> : null}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And the code of myNavBar.js :

```
const myNavBar = (props) => {


    const handleTest = (value) => {
        props.handleTest(value);
    }
    return (
        <>
            <Navbar bg="white">
            <Navbar.Brand>Test</Navbar.Brand>
            <Nav>
              <Nav.Link href="/" onSelect={() => {handleTest(false)}}>Home</Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link href="/test" onSelect={() => {handleTest(true)}}>Test</Nav.Link>
            </Nav>
            </Navbar>
        </>
    )
}

export default myNavBar;
```

I think I lost the modification of the value of `test` which is always equal to `false`

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Unrelated: components should begin with an uppercase letter. It's also unclear what the purpose of the local `handleTest` function is; it's harder to understand what's going on when there's arbitrary code.

Comment: `onSelect` should be `onClick`.in `<Nav.Link.`

Comment: I tried but I got the same error @Sayog

Comment: Related: components should begin with an uppercase letter.

Comment: I change thank you but I got the same problem :/

Comment: your app rerender due to navigation  to a route "/test" that seems to not exist [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-engelbart-t0m50) .I'm not sure if that's a good idea to add some state responsibility in a navigation link component

Comment: @Sayog This is react-bootstrap; `onSelect` is the correct property name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Components must begin with an uppercase letter.
- The code works, but when you click a link the page navigates. If you cancel the event it works as expected.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-yiqre?file=/index.js

Nutshell:

```
<Nav.Link
  href="/"
  onSelect={(_, e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    handleTest(false);
  }}
>
```

Cleaned up, with the navigation in place:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-6vch3?file=/index.js

You're trying to do an SPA, but it is not currently an SPA. You navigate away from the page with the updated state. When the new page loads (/test) your state resets.

There's a variety of ways to create an actual SPA where you define a component per page: you can use any of several routing solutions, there are hook-based solutions, etc.

Plus there's no `/test` path in the code sandbox so it wouldn't know what to do anyway.

Comment: Thank you but It is strange it does not change the path when you click on Home or Test in your code

Comment: @ Tom that's e.preventDefault behaviour so i'm not sure that you can navigate...

Comment: @Tom You're navigating away from the page. Your test component *does* render, but then you navigate away, and it's gone. I think you're *trying* to create an SPA, but that's not what it currently is.